# What is the equivalent shell.nix for nix-shell '<nixpkgs>' -A gnused

Tags: nix, nix-shell

I am trying to explore the gnu sed code base.

I can do this from the command line:

```
nix-shell '<nixpkgs>' -A gnused
unpackPhase
cd sed-4.8
configurePhase
buildPhase
```

and then edit the code under sed etc

However, I would like to use ctags which is not installed:

```
nix-shell -p ctags
```

Installs the package but:

```
nix-shell '<nixpkgs>' -A gnused -p ctags
```

gets the error:

```
error: attribute 'gnused' in selection path 'gnused' not found
```

I realise I must use a shell.nix but I can't find a mkShell example for the above.

P.S. Two invocations of nix-shell achieve the required result but this seems unwieldy:

```
nix-shell -p ctags
nix-shell '<nixpkgs>' -A gnused
```

Answer (score 5):

After waiting a couple of days and getting no response I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VepnulTfu8) talk, which in combination with the examples in the man pages of nix-shell, nix-build and nix-instantiate, produced the required answer.

The equivalent of:

```
nix-shell '<nixpkgs>' -A gnused
```

is:

```
nix-shell -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; gnused'
```

or as a shell.nix:

```
# shell.nix
with import <nixpkgs> {};
gnused
```

The equivalent of:

```
nix-shell -p ctags
```

is:

```
nix-shell -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; runCommand "dummy" { buildInputs = [ ctags ]; } ""'
```

or as a shell.nix:

```
# shell.nix
with import <nixpkgs> {};
runCommand "dummy" { buildInputs = [ ctags ]; } ""
```

N.B. The `runCommand` takes the 3 input parameters, in this case the 3rd parameter is purposely left blank.

To combine both, we use an override but not `gnused.override` which would override the arguments of `mkDerivation` for gnused, instead we use `gnused.overrideAttrs` which overrides the attributes inside of `mkDerivation`.

```
nix-shell -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; gnused.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: { buildInputs = [ ctags ]; })'
```

or as a shell.nix:

```
# shell.nix
with import <nixpkgs> {};
gnused.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: { buildInputs = [ ctags ]; })
```

N.B. To find the attributes of a derivation such as `gnused`, invoke the nix repl using `nix repl '<nixpkgs>'` and type `gnused.` and then press tab for completion or use `nix edit nixpkgs.gnused` which will open up the derivation in the editor set by `$EDITOR`.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing this research!

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for this. I had to search far too long T_T